# Generate random numbers that contain same digits as number n

Tags: java, random

I have to make an array that contains random numbers in certain range, but each number has to contains same digits as number n (user input).Also numbers can be duplicated. For example n=11452 so the generated number can be 221545. Every next number has to contain 1,4,5,2(in this case where n is 11452) I just need an idea for solving this.

Comment: if xxx is your random number just add .n to it

Comment: Does it need to use **all** of the digits of `n` or can some be duplicated?

Comment: User input: 36 -> 9360 or 3612 would be a valid number? Edit your question with an example!

Comment: Can you include some example of what you expect here ?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon  numbers can be duplicated. For example number n is 11452 so the next number can be 221545

Comment: How many digits should the result have?

Comment: What have you tried so far? show us [mcve]

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking more specific problems instead of generic algorithms to solve x problem, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com better. Or as @Nikolay said, show us what algorithm you have already tried.

Comment: It seems to me that the range is the greater part of the challenge. Do all possible numbers in the range have to have the same probability? If the range is 50 through 140, possible numbers are 51, 52, 54, 55, 111, 112, 114, 115, 121, 122, 124, 125, twelve of them. If each needs to have probability one twelfth, I suppose you’d better generate them all and then pick one at random.

Answer (score 0):

1) Determine the number of distinct digits in the user input (in your example 4: 1,2,4,5)
2) Create a random number of at least this number of digits (in your example: at least 1000)
3) Insert the requested digits in random positions of the found number. Make sure these positions are distinct. I.e., make sure no requested digit is overwritten by another one.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

1) Parse the user input number as `String` and add all digits to a `Set`.

2) Convert your set to an array to have access to random index of array.

3) Access the parsed digits in the converted array via random index.

Perhaps, this is not a perfect implementation but the following method will generate a random digit which follows your requirements as i understood. The length of the generated random digit is so long as your user input number.

Just modify it to create an array with generated random numbers as your requirements.

```
public int generate(String number) throws NumberFormatException {
    // 1) parse number and add the digits to a set
    HashSet<Integer> digits = new HashSet<>();
    for (String digitStr : number.split("")) {
        int digit = Integer.parseInt(digitStr);
        digits.add(digit);
    }
    // 2) convert the set to array to access via random index
    Integer[] digitArray = new Integer[number.length()];
    digits.toArray(digitArray);

    String generated = "";
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        // 3) grap a random digit from array and append it to your result
        int randomIndex = Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % number.length();
        generated += digitArray[randomIndex];
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(generated);
}
```